# Assign PropertyGroupDescription with a related table column in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, uicollectionview

I used ListCollectionView to group the ObservableCollection items when I display these items in ComboBox, I have a **account** table that related to **account_type** table, I want to display list of account in ComboBox grouped by their account type

I filled the ObservableCollection with accounts

```
IQueryable<account> accountQuery = _context.account;
ocAccounts = new ObservableCollection<account>(accountQuery);
```

Then, I used ListCollectionView with a GroupDescription

```
ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(ocAccounts);
lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("account_type.name"));
```

The ComboBox group items BUT the group title not display !

[image]

What I miss

Answer (score 0):

I've just created an example of your data and debuged it , you need to change your xaml code to bind your group header and a linq query to join account table with related table.

it's your code (an example of your data with `Northwind` db):

```
     IQueryable<CustomOrder> accountQuery = from cu in context.Customers join 
                                            o in context.Orders on cu.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                                            orderby cu.CustomerID
                                            select new CustomOrder
                                            {
                                                cucity=cu.City,
                                               orid=o.OrderID
                                            };

      var ocAccounts = new ObservableCollection<CustomOrder>(accountQuery);
      ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(ocAccounts);
      lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("cucity"));
      this.comboBox.ItemsSource = lcv;
```

After joining that two tables result should be :

```
   internal  class CustomOrder
    {
      public  string cucity { get; set; }
      public int orid { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you need this Xaml:

```
   <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox">
        <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding orid}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

**It's output :**

[image]

Comment: I tried this and yes it works, my question was about how to do that with related database table

Comment: but i don't know what data is in that accountQuery.

Comment: you can join it with linq with account_type table.

Comment: @Mohammed, Yes, But how to do that ?

Comment: i will update my answer, i will create an example of linq join . i would be great if you share your query.

Comment: @Mohammed, Thank you so much .. I’m waiting your answer

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif did your problem sovle?

Comment: name of binding doesn't matter for header if there is only one parameter , it will automatically bind everything you pass to it

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif i'll be greatfull set my answet to correct if it solved your problem.